# Empty div within parent should appear the same

Tags: css, block

If you see the following jsfiddle, the div a elements that have no text appear on a different level than the ones with text. Is there a way with CSS to make these appear in a row whether or not there is text present? (w/o changing the markup).

I set the link elements as block so that they would be the same height if some link text was empty

http://jsfiddle.net/ch9Ax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `vertical-align:top;` to the rule `#bzm .button` fixed it in my test browser

Comment: curious, too if someone has a prblm with it. of the suggestions offered (height, float instead of inline-block) this affects the surrounding style the least.

Answer (score 1):

Add height:27px to your bzm.button :) This will ensure that its the same size, with, or without content inside of it.

```
#bzm .button {
display: inline-block;
width: 90px;
height:27px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use float css attribute instead of display: inline-block for the .button class.

i.e.:

```
#bzm .button {
display: inline-block;
width: 90px;
}
```

to

```
#bzm .button {
float: left;
width: 90px;
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ch9Ax/12/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the

```
#bzm .button {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 90px;
}
```

Chnage that to

```
#bzm .button {
    float:left;
    width: 90px;
}
```

And style accordingly.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/ch9Ax/14/